# How can i set viewbag value to hidden field and access from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can I set viewbag value into hidden fiels and access the value from jquery

Comment: var someValue = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeProperty))

Comment: is getting null value in debug

Comment: @user2818541 How do you set it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly then you have answered your question yourself - you need to **set ViewBag value into hidden field and access it from jQuery**.

In View .cshtml file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="someName" value="@ViewBag["ProbablyAnotherName"]"/>
```

In JavaScript:

```
var value = $("#someName").val();
```

Comment: throwing error in cshtml page : Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject''

Answer (score 8):

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnViewBag", (object)ViewBag.yourValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@Html.Hidden("x", ViewBag.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me as following

In View .cshtml file:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.yourValue" id="yourid" />
```